# Cloud app refuses connection on port 80 while 'Allow HTTP traffic' flag is ticked

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have my firewall settings on defaults, what should allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic on my server, but I was only able to connect on 443, but not on 80. What should I do? Cloudflare only works on port 80...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to check if your application is running on port 80:

```
netstat -atunp
```

also, check the firewall rules of the instance, perhaps they are blocking the traffic:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

also, check if the network-tag of the instance match with the firewall rules of your project, your instance should have the network-tag "http-server" and you should have a firewall rule to allow all IPs on the port 80 to the instances with this network-tag

Finally, if everything is correct you can run a tcpdump to check if the traffic reach the instance.

```
 sudo tcpdump -i eth0 "port 80"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: Started the app on port 8080 and then redirected the the requests from 80 to 8080 with IPTABLE, now it seems working.